# jquery datatable rails column sorting is not working properly with rails helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails, using jquery database rails gem for sorting and searching my table data . It's working fine but when I use rails helper methods like number_with_delimiter to display number separated by comma, I'm not getting proper sorting results.

Without using rails helpers I get proper results and my table data is sorting correctly. Please can any one help me?

Here is my code:

Script

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#d3').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
         aaSorting : [[2, 'desc']],  
        });
    });
    </script>
```

In my partial the table data is

```
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered "  id="d3">
          <thead>      
           <tr>
             <th>Folder</th>
             <th>#Files</th>
             <th>Source Lines</th>
             <th>Contents</th>
             <th>Description</th>
           </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
           <td>String data</td>
           <td>numeric data</td>
           <td>numeric data</td>
           <td>string data</td>
           <td>string data</td>


          </tbody>
       </table>
```

Here is my result (3rd column data)

```
SourceLines

 994
 98
 974
 .
 .
 . 
 101
 1,890
 1,674
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem while adding "Hour(s)" to a value with the pluralize helper. The reason it happens is because datatables sees the value as a string, not a numeric, and sorts it as one.

My solution was to add a hidden span before my real value that could be sorted correctly as a string. The hidden span value is the numeric with enough preceding '0's as to make it a consistent length as the other values in that column.

```
def datatable_numeric_sort num
    content_tag(:span, number_with_precision(num, :precision => 2).to_s.rjust(10, '0'), :style => "display:none")
end
```

Given a num of 100.5, it will produce:

```
<span style="display:none">0000100.50</span>
```

.to_s.rjust(10, '0') says "append a '0' to this string until it is length 10"
It can be any length, i used 10 because my strings should never be longer.

In my case, number_with_precision was necessary because my numeric was a decimal and you need a consistent position for the decimal point in the string.

To use:

```
<td><%= datatable_numeric_sort record.value%><%= pluralize record.value, "Hour" %></td>
```